# Postgres generated column incorrect

Tags: postgresql

I am on postgres 14.2. This is my table

```
    Column     |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                             Default
---------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------
 id            | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('my_table_seq'::regclass)
 foosname      | text                        |           | not null |
 abbaxd        | text                        |           | not null |
 created_at    | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |
 total         | integer                     |           | not null |
 complete      | integer                     |           | not null | 0
 failed        | integer                     |           | not null | 0
 is_completed  | boolean                     |           |          | generated always as ((complete + failed) = total) stored
 updated_at    | timestamp without time zone |           |          |
```

I get this result when I run the query `select total, complete, failed from my_table where is_completed = 'f'`

```
total   | complete | failed
------------------------------------+---------------+----------+--------
9363950 |  9362414 |   1536
34      |        1 |     33
9363300 |  9361757 |   1543
```

All the three records obey the law `complete + failed = total`. Why is there this discrepancy? Is there anyway to correct it?

**Edit**
Not all rows have this discrepancy. Right now 3 / 14 rows have this.

Comment: [Works for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c1be61c8ca169c20ab2beb0a098891d4)

Comment: Should `imported` be `complete` in your sample output?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for pointing that out. Corrected it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it works for me as well in most cases. But there are these rows lingering which don't seem to follow the rule.

Comment: @Ashwin, see if you can create a https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14 that demonstrates the problem and post back the url

Comment: @Lennart Unfortunately I am not able to reproduce it on the dbfiddle link. The updates to the table are done by code concurrently. Could this be an issue eminating from there?

Comment: Unless you use uncommitted read isolation level it should not be an issue. What happens if you query `SELECT id, (complete + failed) = TOTAL FROM mytable  INTERSECT SELECT id, is_completed FROM mytable` How many rows compared with the number of rows in the table do you get?

Comment: @Lennart apologies for the delayed reply. I get a difference of 4 rows (the table has grown now as well).  It was  3/14 when I posted this message. Now it is at 4/68.

Comment: Have you tried dropping and recreating the is_completed column?

Comment: @Lennart no, would that help?

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with it since it's value deviates from the expression it is supposed to reflect, so in lack of better ideas, that is what I would try

Comment: @Lennart-SlavaUkraini that solves the problem for now. Will have to wait and see if this comes up again.